# printf() outputs data after the struct field

Tags: c, file, struct, io

I am opening an Android boot image and reading its headers. However, when printing the value of the first field, it also prints the next byte **after** its end.

I noticed that this only happens when the struct contains more than 1 field.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
  typedef struct {
    uint8_t foo[8];
    // Commenting the line below fixes the problem. 
    uint8_t bar;
  } magic_struct;
  magic_struct magic;

  FILE *fp = fopen("android13_boot.img", "r");
  fread(&magic, sizeof(magic), 1, fp);
  fclose(fp);

  printf("%s\n", magic.foo);
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror file.c && ./a.out
ANDROID!�
```

Comment: You have not shown the exact content of the file. Perhaps there is no string terminator, and the unused bytes of the `struct` have not been initialised. They contain 'random' data. You have undefined behaviour which is likely to be inconsistent as you juggle the code around, rather then being 'fixed'.

Comment: If the file contains `ANDROID!` that is 8 characters, so `uint8_t foo[8];` isn't big enough to store a proper C string which can be passed to functions that expect a string.

Comment: @WeatherVane You're right. The string does not have a null terminator. Thanks for such fast reply!

Comment: Perhaps `uint8_t foo[9];` and then `size_t len = fread(&magic, 1, sizeof(magic), fp); if(len < 9) magic.foo[len] = '\0';`. Note the swapped order of `fread`'s arguments.

Comment: `printf( "%.8s\n", magic.foo );` works, too...